Has there been progress on Hamiltonicity in 4-connected claw-free graphs with a constant maximum degree?
In 1984, Matthews and Sumner [1] conjectured that every 4-connected claw-free graph is Hamiltonian, and this conjecture is still wide open.
I would like to know if there has been any progress on this conjecture when the maximum degree of these graphs is restricted to a small range. For example, can it be asserted that every 4-connected claw-free graph with the maximum degree of 10 is Hamiltonian?
[1] M. M. Matthews and D. P. Sumner, Hamiltonian results in K1,3 -free graphs,J Graph Theory 8(1) (1984), 139–146.

Cubic graphs? Do you mean 4-connected 4-regular  claw-free graph?
